# Why I'm getting Rendered more hooks error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was wonder what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm getting this error: "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."

```
export default function ProductDetails() {
    //Use State
    const {qty, increaseQty, decreaseQty, onAdd, setQty} = useStateContext();

    //Reset Qty

    useEffect(() => {
        setQty(1);
    }, []);
    //Fetch Slug
    const {query} = useRouter();
    //Fetch Graphql data
    const [results] = useQuery({
        query: GET_PRODUCT_QUERY,
        variables: {slug: query.slug}
    })
    const {data, fetching, error} = results;
     //Check for data coming in
    if(fetching) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if(error) return <p>Oh no....</p>;
    //Extract Product Data
    const {title,description, image, gallery } = data.products.data[0].attributes;
    const [img, setImg] = useState(gallery.data[0].attributes.formats.medium.url);
    console.log(img);


    //Create a toast 

    const notify = () => {
        toast.success(`${title} added to your cart`, {duration: 1500});
    }

    return(
        <DetailsStyle>
            <Gallery>
                <img src={gallery.data[0].attributes.formats.medium.url} alt={title} />
                <Thumbnails>
                    {gallery.data.map((image, index) => (
                            <SingleThumb key={index} >
                                <img src={image.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url} alt={title} />
                            </SingleThumb>
                        )
                    )}
                </Thumbnails>
            </Gallery>
            <ProductInfo>
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                <p>{description}</p>
                <Quantity>
                    <span>Quantity</span>
                    <button><AiFillMinusCircle onClick={decreaseQty} /></button>
                    <p>{qty}</p>
                    <button><AiFillPlusCircle onClick={increaseQty}/></button>
                </Quantity>
                <Buy onClick={() => {
                    onAdd(data.products.data[0].attributes, qty)
                    notify();
                }}>Add To Cart</Buy>
            </ProductInfo>
        </DetailsStyle>
    )
}
```

Something wrong is in this line: const [img, setImg] = useState();

Why I can't use more hooks here.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this?

Comment: Move this line `const [img, setImg] = useState();` to the beginning of your component.

Comment: I tried to move it to beginning, but then I get this: "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'gallery' before initialization".

Because I can't access my query results.

Comment: Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using early `return`

and this line of code won't execute every time:

```js
    const [img, setImg] = useState(gallery.data[0].attributes.formats.medium.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only *conditionally* called:

```
const [img, setImg] = useState(gallery.data[0].attributes.formats.medium.url);
```

Because the component has earlier conditional return statements.  Move it to earlier in the function.  (Generally I invoke `useState` operations right away.)

Hooks need to always be consistently called in the same order on every render.

Answer (score 0):

You declare your state after some return statements. It means that if you had any errors or you were in loading state, the state is not defined. But maybe in the next render, the data is set and then your state will be defined with the inital value (gallery.data[0].attributes.formats.medium.url).

It's forbidden in react because all of the hooks should always be in the same order on every single render. In order to fix this, you should change the place of your useState for img.

Hope it helps:

```js
export default function ProductDetails() {
    const [img, setImg] = useState('');
    
    //Use State
    const {qty, increaseQty, decreaseQty, onAdd, setQty} = useStateContext();

    //Reset Qty

    useEffect(() => {
        setQty(1);
    }, []);
    //Fetch Slug
    const {query} = useRouter();
    //Fetch Graphql data
    const [results] = useQuery({
        query: GET_PRODUCT_QUERY,
        variables: {slug: query.slug}
    })
    const {data, fetching, error} = results;
    //Check for data coming in
    //Extract Product Data

    useEffect(() => {
        if(results && results.data) {
          const {data} = results
          const { gallery } = data.products.data[0].attributes;
          setImg(gallery.data[0].attributes.formats.medium.url);
        }
    }, [results]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(img);
    }, [img]);

    //Create a toast 
    const notify = (title) => {
        toast.success(`${title} added to your cart`, {duration: 1500});
    }

    if(fetching) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    } else if(error) {
        return <p>Oh no....</p>;
    } else if(data) {
        const { title, description, image, gallery } = data.products.data[0].attributes;

        return(
            <DetailsStyle>
                <Gallery>
                    <img src={gallery.data[0].attributes.formats.medium.url} alt={title} />
                    <Thumbnails>
                        {gallery.data.map((image, index) => (
                                <SingleThumb key={index} >
                                    <img src={image.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url} alt={title} />
                                </SingleThumb>
                            )
                        )}
                    </Thumbnails>
                </Gallery>
                <ProductInfo>
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                    <p>{description}</p>
                    <Quantity>
                        <span>Quantity</span>
                        <button><AiFillMinusCircle onClick={decreaseQty} /></button>
                        <p>{qty}</p>
                        <button><AiFillPlusCircle onClick={increaseQty}/></button>
                    </Quantity>
                    <Buy onClick={() => {
                        onAdd(data.products.data[0].attributes, qty)
                        notify(title);
                    }}>Add To Cart</Buy>
                </ProductInfo>
            </DetailsStyle>
        )
    } else {
      return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Still getting this: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')" in one of useEffects where is const gallery = ...

Comment: @Get_Date Sorry, I edited my answer. Check the new one.

Comment: Same issue at line const { gallery } = data.products.data[0].attributes;

Comment: @Get_Date I did a simple edit after the previous edit. I think you missed it. Check the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no return before hooks.

These lines

```
if(fetching) return <p>Loading...</p>;
if(error) return <p>Oh no....</p>;
```

should be after all hooks